# tcp client "connection refused" if not reading input stream of process, which started the tcp server?

Tags: java, tcp, inputstream

When I start the tcp server on command line it output's:

> java -jar tcpServer.jar --tcp=7000
>
> > waiting on tcp client on port ...

if I run the server in code:

```
String command = "java -jar ../tcpServer.jar --tcp=" + port;
tcpServer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

and try to connect

```
Socket client = new Socket(port);
```

i get:

> connection refused

but if  I read the input of the tcp server process after
starting the tcp server

```
String command = "java -jar ../tcpServer.jar --tcp=" + port;
tcpServer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(tcpServer.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

> waiting on tcp client on port ...

```
Socket client = new Socket(port);
```

> connected

Is this a regular behaviour or specific to the jar
file which I execute ?

Comment: Just to get you right: You are using the `exec` method to execute a jar file which starts a TCP server?

Comment: exactly, it is executing a jar, which starts a tcp server

Comment: It is specific to the JAR which you execute. Clearly it prints that message *before* it is actually true, i.e. before it creates the server socket, and if the outout isn't read it blocks.

Comment: could you post your comment as answer, so I can accept it as answer ?